# Can I use DevExpress related "DxCore" for dialogs/tool windows?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, extensibility

Can I use DevExpress related "DxCore" to extend VS functionality to add new dialogs/toolwindows etc.?

If so, how is it different from VS SDK (focusing on dialogs/tool windows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DXCore has great wizards for creating and adding tool windows into your plug-in projects. The DXCore tool windows are the same as Visual Studio ones, for example, Solution Explorer, Toolbox or Property Browser. Creating a tool window plug-in using DXCore is easy. Just arrange your components in the tool window designer, set a few properties, and compile the project.